# Order not placed payment received

Tags: android, paypal

I have an android application where user can buy stuffs . I have used PAYPAL payment gateway its working good.I place the order only once the user has made payment . Suppose user pays his stuff and his payment is received but due to network connectivity problem user's order wasn't placed. How can i overcome such problems ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to track the status of order.

1. UnPaid
2. Paid and Order Failed
3. Paid and Order Success

If paid then you have to check the status after user have the internet connection